# Train default Perceptron Tagger

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I can't figure out how to extend/retrain existing model. I don't wanna train my own tagger from the scratch, i just want to take existing and make some changes, based on my needs. For example

```
tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=True) 
tagger.train([[('restaurant','NN')]])

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize("Show me restaurant in Berlin")
tags = tagger.tag(tokens)

for i in tags:
    print(i)
```

This of course, outputs by default:

> <'Show', 'VB'> <'me', 'PRP'> <'restaurant', 'VB'> <'in', 'IN'>
>   <'Berlin', 'NNP'>

What i expect is restaurant - NN.
Or also, there is a common problem with entities in lower case like berlin, south korea etc ( which will be: NN, JJ, NN ). Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: if the answer is correct i would ask you to mark as correct, so i can gain a little bit of reputation, please =) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice tou to train the tagger only on lowercase words, so you won't encouter problems like the one you said about the word 'berlin' and 'Berlin'.

I don't know how `PerceptronTagger` work in detail, but i suggest you this. In order to retrain a model when you have new data you have to **repeat the training process allover again** on the "updated" data.

Otherwise, if the tagger has some kind of internal dictionary, maby a `dict` that associates a word with the relative tag, you can try to update it with your new data, in this case "<'resturant'><'NN'>